# How to access Oracle DB in VirtualBox from Host (windows)

Tags: oracle, networking, virtualbox

I installed VirtualBox with a Oracle VM.

Now I simply try to access the Oracle Database of the VM from the host environment, but it doesn't work.

ipconfig on my host shows an IP number, but when I try to open this (Port 80), i get the content of localhost of the host system instead of the content of the server in the VirtualBox.

Which is the proper network setting ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually do a bridged connection so the vm will pick up an ip address from my router's dhcp; if that option is not available, your other option is to employ port forwarding where you assign an unused port on the host machine to forward to the port on the vm. The virtual box manual has a lot of useful info on both of these options. Let us know if you need additional info or examples.

Answer (score 22):

### - Use Host-Only Networking on your guest machine

[image]

### - See if the server (WEB, DB etc.) is running.

[image]

### - Mouse-over network icon on status bar to note ip address

[image]

### - From your host browser send a request to your quest server

[image]

Comment: Problem with this approach is that VM Guest now does not have Internet access.  I still have not explored various options, but it appears that doing bridged configuration is the best way to do this thus far.

Comment: No. Guest Internet works fine with this approach. I think it is something specific to your configuration.

Comment: you can always add more than one network interface so you keep the normal NAT for your internet access and the host-only for access from your machine.

Answer (score 3):

Turn off the Windows Firewall on the Virtual PC. I've just fixed my HTTP request from Host to VM by turning off the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

In the virtual box go to the settings->Network->Adapter and select Bridge Adapter for  (Attached to) field. Don't forget to turn off your firewall in the machine.
[image]