# Connecting db in host machine from Virtualbox -

Tags: oracle11g, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I just installed Win7 (32 bit) on my Virtual Box v4.3.20. I'll be installing Informatica PowerCenter v9.5.1 in the windows environment.
My host OS is Win8 where the Virtual Box is installed.

But, I have my database Oracle XE 11.2.0.4.0 installed on Win8 host OS.

My doubt is - will I be able to access this database from inside the virtual Win7 OS ?
If yes, how?

Please assist. Help much appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
-Ranit

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one similar question here on StackOverflow -
[How to access Oracle DB in VirtualBox from Host (windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117610/how-to-access-oracle-db-in-virtualbox-from-host-windows)

And just searching the web I was able to see a relatively recent post -
https://superuser.com/questions/310697/connect-to-the-host-machine-from-a-virtualbox-guest-os

That said, it looks like your biggest problem may be the firewall running on the client OS, in your case Win 7.  You will need to open the appropriate port(s) that Oracle is using.
Relative to your Win 7 client running in VirtualBox, Oracle running on the host is not different than oracle running on a box somewhere else.  It is still just an TCP connection to Oracle server.  So it would be setup in a similar fashion.
Hopefully this gives you a starting point.